# Show full documentation for functions Xcode?

Tags: xcode

When i'm using xcode with a C header, i see only the first line of documentation for a function:

For example, this is a function in my header.

In my header, the documentation looks like this:

```
/**
 * Perform a ticket-create request and return the result.
 *
 * All logs uploaded between this ticket and the last ticket created for this device will
 * automatically be included with this ticket.
 *
 * @param p0 The details to include with the ticket.
 * @param p1 The contact information to include with the ticket.
 *
 * @return a structure where r0 contains the ticket id or -1 if there was an error and r1 contains an error if any.
 */

extern struct VcbLogCreateTicket_return VcbLogCreateTicket(char* p0, char* p1);
```

But when i go to that function in xcode, i only see the first line like so:

[image]

How do I get it to show the full documentation, preferably including parameters and return? Is this even an option in xcode?

Comment: You should be able to option-click on any symbol to get its full documentation.

Comment: @Rudedog that works! if you want to submit it as an answer, feel free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can option-click on any symbol to get its full documentation.